# How to populate entities from database table in spring boot application

Tags: mysql, database, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

> **I am trying to create a springboot application and has created database and table. Now need to populate entities from database table that is created. Spring sts is my editor. I haven't created any separate configuration class that sets datasource etc as i expect springboot to do this. Do i need to having separate configuration class for establishing connection. But when trying to populate entities getting the following error. **

```
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Below given is the application files

**> This is the application.properties file.**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

server.port=${PORT:8081
```

}

**> This is my pom.xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.javabrains.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-security-jdbc</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**> Main Class**

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSecurityJdbcApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityJdbcApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Please help to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: try to specify the following property `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` (instead of `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect`)

Comment: Not working @Vasiliy Sarzhynskyi

Comment: @Kleber Mota Any Suggestion to this problem

Comment: Any Suggestion to this issue @Andy Wilkinson

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in your application.properties file.

You have:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

But there is no `properties` attribute on `jpa`.
Try removing properties, your line should look like this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried with the dialect `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` ? Right now you have `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`

Comment: Yes that also I have tried, but didn't work. @Alex.